# How do I cycle trough functions on a press of a button in Wiring?

Tags: button, arduino, switch-statement

I am programming a button that cycles through different functions and cant get it to work. It always gets to the first case in the switch but never gets to the second one. I thought I would use the "prevButtState" but then thought of this way of coding it but well, it does not work and I forgot how I meant to use this :D

my code:

```
#include "arduino.h"

int LED=13;
int butt=4;
int buttState=0;
int prevButtState=0; 
int counter=0;

void setup() {
pinMode(LED, OUTPUT);
pinMode(butt, INPUT);
}

void loop() {
    buttStatus();
    if (buttState==1){
        counter++;
    }
    switch(counter){
        case 1:
        digitalWrite(LED,HIGH);
        buttState=0;
        while(buttState==0){
        buttStatus();
        if (buttState==1){
        counter=2;
        }
        }
        break;
        case 2:
        digitalWrite(LED,LOW);
        buttState=0;
        while(buttState==0){
        buttStatus();
        if (buttState==1){
            counter=1;
            }
        }
        break;
    }
}

void buttStatus(){
    buttState=digitalRead(butt); 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out how to do it, I tottaly didnt understand how switch state works in C...

this is the working code:

```
int LED=13;
int butt=4;
int buttState=0;
int currentButtState=0;
int prevButtState=0;
int counter=0;

void setup() {
pinMode(LED, OUTPUT);
pinMode(butt, INPUT);

}

void loop() {
    buttStatus();
    if (buttState==1){
        delay(25);
      buttStatus();
      if(buttState==0){
      currentButtState=prevButtState+1;
      }
    }else delay(100);
  
    switch(currentButtState){
        case 1:
        
        digitalWrite(LED,HIGH);
        prevButtState = currentButtState;
  
        break;
        case 2:
        digitalWrite(LED,LOW);
        prevButtState = 0;
        
        break;
    }
}

void buttStatus(){
    buttState=digitalRead(butt); 
}
```